# How do I print the number of words that begin with a certain character?

Tags: c++, computer-science

This is for an intro c++ class, the prompt reads:

Print the number of words that begin with a certain character. Let the user enter that character.

Although, I'm not sure how to do this.

Do I use parsing strings? I tried this because they inspect string data type but I kept getting errors so I took it out and changed it to characters. I want to learn how to do the "total_num" (total number of words that start with the letter the user chooses) and I also need some help with my for loop.

Example of desired output

> user types in: a
> outputs: "Found 1270 words that begin with a"
>
> user types in: E
> outputs: "Found 16 words that begin with E"
>
> user types in: #
> outputs: "Found 0 words that begin with #"

(I think I got this part down for non-alphabetical)

The data is from a file called `dict.txt`, it's a list of many words.

Here's a small sample of what it contains:

```
D
d
D.A.
dab
dabble
dachshund
dad
daddy
daffodil
dagger
daily
daintily
dainty
dairy
dairy cattle
dairy farm
daisy
dally
Dalmatian
dam
damage
damages
damaging
dame
```

My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_WORD = 21880;//amount of words in file
struct dictionary { string word; };

void load_file(dictionary blank_array[])
{
  ifstream data_store;
  data_store.open("dict.txt");

  if (!data_store)
  {
    cout << "could not open file" << endl;
    exit(0);
  }

}

int main()
{
  dictionary file_array[NUM_WORD];
  char user_input;
  int total_num = 0;

  load_file(file_array);

  cout << "Enter a character" << endl;
  cin >> user_input;

  if (!isalpha(user_input))
  {
    cout << "Found 0 that begin with " << user_input << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  for (int counter = 0; counter< NUM_WORD; counter++)

  {
    if (toupper(user_input) == toupper(file_array[counter].word[0]));
    //toupper is used to make a case insensitive search
    {
      cout << "Found " << total_num << " that begin                                   with " << user_input << endl;
      //total_num needs to be the total number of words that start with that letter
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest that load_file returns a std::vector<std::string>() at the very least?  Since you don't ask the user for multiple didgits though, I'd ask the user for the character first, and then go through the file and count.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to make your life simpler e.g. using a `vector` as the comment suggested.

Let's look at your for loop. There are some obvious syntax problems.

```
int main()
{
      dictionary file_array[NUM_WORD];
      char user_input;
      int total_num = 0;

      load_file(file_array);

      cout << "Enter a character" << endl;
      cin>>user_input;

      if(!isalpha(user_input))
      {
         cout << "Found 0 that begin with " << user_input << endl;
         return 0;
      }

      for(int counter = 0;counter< NUM_WORD; counter++)
      {
          if (toupper(user_input) == toupper(file_array[counter].word[0]));
           //                                                             ^no semi-colon here!
          //toupper is used to make a case insensitive search
          {
            cout<< "Found " << total_num << " that begin  with "<<
                                               user_input       << endl;
        //total_num needs to be the total number of words that start with that letter
          }

      }//<<< needed to end the for loop
}
```

Let's get the for loop right. You want to count the matches in a loop and then report when you have finished the loop.

```
      int total_num = 0;

      //get character and file

      for(int counter = 0;counter< NUM_WORD; counter++)
      {
           if (toupper(user_input) == toupper(file_array[counter].word[0]))
                              ^^^no semi-colon here!
          {
               ++total_num;
          }
      }
      cout<< "Found " << total_num << " that begin  with "<<                                                                                          user_input       << endl;
```